# How to install packages using conda within a singularity container

Tags: containers, conda, mamba

I have the following definition file which works great until the very end:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:20.04

%post
  apt-get -y update
  apt-get -y upgrade
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
  apt-get -y install default-jre
  apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install wget git zlib1g-dev curl openssh-client tar gzip ca-ce\
rtificates build-essential cmake


  #Install Mamba
  readonly mamba_installer="Mambaforge-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh"
  readonly mamba_version="4.10.3-4"
  readonly mamba_prefix="/opt/mamba"
  wget "https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/download/${mamba_version}/${mamba_install\
er}"
  bash "${mamba_installer}" -b -p "${mamba_prefix}"
  rm "${mamba_installer}"
  export PATH="/opt/mamba/bin:$PATH"

  PATH=$PATH:/bbmap/
  mamba config --add channels defaults
  mamba config --add channels conda-forge
  mamba config --add channels bioconda

  mamba create -y -n blee python=3.6 pip
  mamba init
  . /opt/mamba/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh
  . activate blee
  #mamba install --yes -c conda-forge -c bioconda medaka openblas==0.3.3 spoa racon minimap2
```

But when it comes to the last line, time to install things from the environment it seems like it is using python 3.9 instead of the one it's supposed to: python3.6

What am I missing?

Comment: FYI all Bioconda packages are already available as containers (https://biocontainers.pro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mamba install` command needs a `-n` flag to include your environment name so it installs the packages accordingly (as in, uses the Python version specified by your `create env` command).

Changing your mamba install command to the following should work:

```
mamba install -n blee --yes -c conda-forge -c bioconda medaka openblas==0.3.3 spoa racon minimap2
```

Comment: Thank you! But do you understand why isn't it working as is if I am running 
` . activate blee` right before??

Comment: I believe that the way you're activating the mamba env doesn't seem right. Have you tried just running `mamba activate blee` after `mamba init`?

Comment: If it's anything like Docker, each command is run in a new shell subprocess and activation is non-persistent. Instead you need to chain commands (`&&`). But specifying the exact environment is the robust (better) solution.

Comment: Agreed! Even when chaining a command to activate an environment, it's best to have the environment name specified.